# I have an issue with hiding text fields

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a bar button item. Which will toggle 12 text fields' visibilty. I have tried the method below but even if I click the button while it's title is = Hide, It still calls the first method.

```
- (IBAction)namesButton:(id)sender {
if ((self.namesButton.title = @"Names")) {
_text1.hidden = FALSE;
    _text2.hidden = FALSE;
    _text3.hidden = FALSE;
    _text4.hidden = FALSE;
    _text5.hidden = FALSE;
    _text6.hidden = FALSE;
    _text7.hidden = FALSE;
    _text8.hidden = FALSE;
    _text9.hidden = FALSE;
    _text10.hidden = FALSE;
    _text11.hidden = FALSE;
    _text12.hidden = FALSE;
    self.namesButton.title = @"Hide";
    NSLog(@"Now Showing");
    return;

}
 else if ((_namesButton.title = @"Hide")) {
    _text1.hidden = TRUE;
    _text2.hidden = TRUE;
    _text3.hidden = TRUE;
    _text4.hidden = TRUE;
    _text5.hidden = TRUE;
    _text6.hidden = TRUE;
    _text7.hidden = TRUE;
    _text8.hidden = TRUE;
    _text9.hidden = TRUE;
    _text10.hidden = TRUE;
    _text11.hidden = TRUE;
    _text12.hidden = TRUE;
    self.namesButton.title = @"Names";
     NSLog(@"Now Hidden");

}
```

}

Comment: if it is a bar button item use like this...if([self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title  isEqual: @"Names"])

Comment: if it is UIButton  if ([self.loginBtn.currentTitle isEqualToString: @"Names" ]) {
        [self.loginBtn setTitle:@"Hide" forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `(self.namesButton.title = @"Names")` assign a value to the title and does not check it.

If you want to compare values in a if use `==` but you can not use the `==` from strings object.

The `==` compares the pointer of the object and it's value, thus for `NSString` compare you should use `([self.namesButton.title isEqualToString:@"Names"])` to check the string is equal.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use = , use isEqualToString instead like following:

```
[self.namesButton.title isEqualToString:@"Names"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
- (IBAction)namesButton:(id)sender {
    if ([self.namesButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Names"]) {
        [self.namesButton setTitle: @"Hide" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _text1.hidden = FALSE;
        _text2.hidden = FALSE;
        _text3.hidden = FALSE;
        _text4.hidden = FALSE;
        _text5.hidden = FALSE;
        _text6.hidden = FALSE;
        _text7.hidden = FALSE;
        _text8.hidden = FALSE;
        _text9.hidden = FALSE;
        _text10.hidden = FALSE;
        _text11.hidden = FALSE;
        _text12.hidden = FALSE;
        NSLog(@"Now Showing");
        return;

    }
    else if ([self.namesButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Hide"]) {
        [self.namesButton setTitle: @"Names" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _text1.hidden = TRUE;
        _text2.hidden = TRUE;
        _text3.hidden = TRUE;
        _text4.hidden = TRUE;
        _text5.hidden = TRUE;
        _text6.hidden = TRUE;
        _text7.hidden = TRUE;
        _text8.hidden = TRUE;
        _text9.hidden = TRUE;
        _text10.hidden = TRUE;
        _text11.hidden = TRUE;
        _text12.hidden = TRUE;
        NSLog(@"Now Hidden");

    }
}
```